# Is it possible to use regular expression at second argument of fscanf()?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array, scanf

I want to read 'm' number of integers separated by space so I am not aware of how many format modifier would be used.

According to PHP documentation

> **Description**
>
> `mixed fscanf ( resource $handle , string $format [, mixed &$... ] )`
>
> The function fscanf() is similar to sscanf(), but it takes its input
>   from a file associated with handle and interprets the input according
>   to the specified format, which is described in the documentation for
>   sprintf().
>
> Any white-space in the format string matches any white-space in the
>   input stream. This means that even a tab \t in the format string can
>   match a single space character in the input stream.
>
> Each call to fscanf() reads one line from the file.

*So is it possible to use variable format modifier in 2nd argument of fscanf()*

eg.

```
fscanf($_fp,"%d\t%d\t%d\n");
```

Here it is 3 %d modifiers because of the known array size.

I know `fgets($_fp)` or `fscanf($_fp,"%[^\n]")` can be used but in `fgets($_fp)` will return string while `fscanf($_fp,"%[^\n]")` will return unformulated result. In both these cases I wont be able to do this

```
arr[i] = fscanf($_fp,"%d\t%d\t%d\n"); //Because I need a integer array
```

where `arr[i]` contains another array which stores the array returned by
`fscanf($_fp,"%d\t%d\t%d\n")`.

i.e.. won't be able to use fscanf() directly to initialize array. 
Supposing

I/P

2 3 4

2 3 4

4 5 1

but I/p can be of any size so is it possible to use regular expression or anything else in second argument of fscanf() so as to store in array directly.

Comment: Do you know `m`? You can use `fscanf($_fp, str_repeat('%d\t', $m));`

Comment: Yeah $m value is known. Thank you it works but is there any way without calling any other function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `fscanf()` that understands regular expressions. You can read the data from the file one line at a time using [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) then parse it using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

If you know that the line contains only numbers separated by spaces then [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) does the job too.